# No matching function call error using member initializer list

Tags: c++, constructor, initializer-list

I have 2 classes : `point` and `droite`.

Header file for Point:

```cpp
class point
{
    int abs,ord;
    public:
        point(int,int);
        ~point();

};
```

cpp file for Point

```cpp
point::point(int a,int b):abs(a),ord(b)
{
    cout<<"++ constructor point "<<abs<<"  "<<ord<<endl;
}

point::~point()
{
    cout<<"-- destruction abs= "<<abs<<"et ord= "<<ord<<endl;
}
```

Header file for Droite:

```cpp
class droite: public point{

    point s1;
    point s2;
    public:
        droite(int,int,int,int);
        ~droite();

};
```

cpp file for Droite

```cpp
droite::droite(int a,int b,int c,int d):s1(a,b),s2(c,d)
{
    cout<<"++ constructor of droite "<<a<<""<<b<<""<<c<<""<<d<<endl;
}

droite::~droite(){ cout<<"destructor of droite "<<endl;}
```

And main

```cpp
int main(){
    droite A(1,2,3,4);
}
```

The ouput is :

> droite.cpp|12|  error: no matching function for call to
>   'point::point()'

My question is: why am I getting this error while there's a constructor with arguments for point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a syntax error. I'm not sure why you are redeclaring `public point` in your droite header file.

```cpp
class droite: public point{

    point s1;
    point s2;
    public:
        droite(int,int,int,int);
        ~droite();

};
```

Comment: Thank you so much , a friend of mine wrote the initial code , the " : public point " ie inheritance shouldn't be there

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be no good reason why you define `droite` as being derived from `point`, and then have **two** `point` members of `droite`. However, if you do need this derivation, then you will need an *explicit* call to the base class (`point`) constructor with the two `int` arguments in your definition of the `driote` constructor:

```cpp
droite::droite(int a, int b, int c, int d) : point(0,0), s1(a, b), s2(c, d)
{
    cout << "++ constructor of droite " << a << "" << b << "" << c << "" << d << endl;
}
```

Comment: You are right , the derivation shouldn't have been there